# WxPython Making Window Scrollable after window goes less than a particular size

Tags: python, scroll, responsive-design, resize, wxpython

I know that this thing is done by using ScrolledWindow or ScrolledPanel by some way, but I exactly don't know how.
Below is the minimal code for the same

```
    screenSize = wx.DisplaySize()
    screenWidth = screenSize[0]
    screenHeight = screenSize[1]

    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.nb = wx.Notebook(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    sizer_1.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    
    self.notebook_1_pane_1 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self.nb,-1, size=(screenWidth,400), pos=(0,28), style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
    self.notebook_1_pane_1.SetupScrolling()
```

Even on the screen where defining self.notebook_1_pane_1 as a simple panel (using wx.Panel) gives proper GUI, making it a scrolledpanel is adding scrollbars even there and making all sizers take additional spaces.

Please help!

Comment: This is a statement, not a question and certainly not a question that has either, a minimal, reproducible example or shows any effort.

Comment: Hey, that is the question mate!
I want to make window Scrollable, and I know that the mentioned things are meant to be used for it, but when I use it, I am unable to achieve what I want

Comment: I have added a code snippet also

Comment: `Hey, that is the question mate!` - Good, clear, concise questions, get similar answers. Poor, confused, inexact questions, get poor answers or no answers. If the question has had no effort put into it, there is no incentive to attempt an answer. People move on, it's like life!